# access multiple buckets in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My manager has an AWS account n using his credentials we create buckets per employee. Now i want to access another bucket through command line. So is it possible that i can access two buckets (mine and one more)? I have the access key for both buckets. But still i am not able to access both the buckets simultaneously.so that i could upload and download my files on which ever bucket  i want..?

I have already tried changing access key and security in my s3config. But it didn't serve the purpose.

I have been already granted the ACL for that new bucket.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best you can do without having a single access key that has permissions for both buckets is create a separate .s3cfg file. I'm assuming you're using s3cmd.

```
s3cmd --configure -c .s3cfg_bucketname
```

Will  allow you to create a new configuration in the config file `.s3cfg_bucketname`. From then on when you are trying to access that bucket you just have to add the command line flag to specify which configuration to use:

```
s3cmd -c .s3cfg_bucketname ls
```

Of course you could add a bash function to your `.bashrc` (now I'm assuming bash... lots of assumptions! Let me know if I'm in the wrong, please) to make it even simpler:

```
function s3bucketname(){
    s3cmd -c ~/.s3cfg_bucketname "$@"
}
```

Usage:

```
s3bucketname ls
```

Comment: This is a good option assuming you cannot be granted access via IAM policy for the original user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which command line tool you are using, if you are using Timothy Kay's [tool](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-S3/739) 
than you will find that the [documentation](http://timkay.com/aws/) allows you the set the access key and secret key as environment variables and not only in a config file so you can set them in command line before the put command.

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the developer of Bucket Explorer and you can use its Transfer panel with two credentials and perform operation between your and other bucket.

for more details read [Copy Move Between two different account](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--copy-s3-objects-in-a-single-operation-put-object-copy.html)